# Raspberry pi OS crashing

Tags: pi-3b+, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, storage

I am using raspberry pi 3B+ for a project. I have installed the bullseye which is currently the OLD STABLE.
The raspbian mirror that I am using is: http://ftp.tsukuba.wide.ad.jp/Linux/raspbian/raspbian/  because some of the applications, it threw error of connection in the original raspbian mirror.

I have installed the following so far:

rustdesk
GPIO library
Adafruit library for Adc
rtc settings

and i am running some services.

previously i used sandisk sd 32GB cards and it is working fine till now. Just few days back i am using hp SD cards and after running a day it stops .
I have attached the picture below.

[image]

from another HP sd card I am getting something else. i have attached the picture below:

[image]

Comment: From what I can read of the rather poor image your SD Card is corrupt. It is (occasionally) possible to repair but the best option is to restore from your backup or re-install.

Comment: I have done the same thing to another two HP sdcard and they also have crashed after working a  day.